# Requirement to disclose information during jury selection

Tags: united-states, jury, voir-dire

During jury selection and you are a potential jury member, are you required to answer the question if asked whether you own a firearm or are a member of the NRA?

Comment: An attempt to keep this kind of information from the court is a good indicator that the potential juror has no business deciding the case.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It could be that the individual doesn't believe the court or any other government agency has any business knowing whether they own firearms or support the NRA.

Comment: Exactly. And if he is really so blinded by those feelings that he doesn't realize they could affect deliberations, he has no business deciding the case.

Answer (score 7):

If you are directly asked a question, you might sit there silently or explicitly refuse to answer, and the judge may order you to answer (refusing the order would be contempt). A non-responsive answer when being individually examined by an attorney is to be corrected by re-asking the question, to get a complete answer.
However, if the pool is asked a generic question ("Is anybody here a member of the NRA ~ does anyone here work for Google, raise your hand") silence (or not raising your hand) would be perjury. See [People v. Meza](https://law.justia.com/cases/california/court-of-appeal/3d/188/1631.html) 188 Cal.App.3d 1631, [People v. Blackwell](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/ca-court-of-appeal/1845701.html) for example.